# UPDATE multiple columns using on query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to set the city_populations Column as follows using 1 CASE command in my table 'customers'

```
Barrie      =   177,061
Toronto     =   2,480,000
Collingwood =   17,290
Thunder Bay =   108,359
```

Ive created 2 querys, but it wont run, any suggestions.

```
UPDATE customers
SET city_population Barrie = 177061, 
                    Toronto = 2480000,
                    Collingwood = 17290, 
                    Thunder Bay =108359 
WHERE city = 'Barrie', 'Toronto', 'Collingwood', 'Thunder Bay';

 UPDATE customers
 SET city_population = 177061, 2480000, 17290, 108359 
 WHERE city = 'Barrie', 'Toronto', 'Collingwood', 'Thunder Bay';
```

Comment: Are Barrie,Toronto,Collingwood, and Thunder Bay columns in your table or it seems to be the rows of your table. Which is which?

Comment: Yes the city column hold these cities and is already created. I had to create a city_population column, which i did. Know i have to populate these cities in city_population with the given population in the query.

Comment: city is a row, city name is the column. Also, city_population is the row and the number of population is the column

Comment: You could have just issued four different updates. It doesn't sound like you'll be doing this more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like this

```
UPDATE `customers`
SET `city_population` = CASE `city`
WHEN 'Barrie' THEN 177061
WHEN 'Toronto' THEN 2480000
....
END,
WHERE `customers` IN ('Barrie', 'Toronto', ...);
```

Comment: Not a problem, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `customers`
SET city_population = CASE city
WHEN 'Barrie' THEN 177061
WHEN 'Toronto' THEN 2480000
WHEN 'Collingwood' THEN 17290
WHEN 'Thunder Bay' THEN 108359  
END
WHERE `city` IN ('Barrie', 'Toronto', 'Collingwood', 'Thunder Bay');
```